# How to select rows according to button pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

If I select a table row under `city` Tab and press `Ok` to highlight the row when I am under `areaOne`,same table row under `city` Tab remains highlighted even if I change it to `areaTwo button`. How do I prevent this from happening?

```
var citySelectedIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
var townSelectedIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
@IBOutlet weak var areaOne: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var areaTwo: UIButton!
 var popValue:Int!

@IBAction func areaSelect(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let areas: [[UIButton]] = [[areaOne],[areaTwo]]
    switch sender {
    case areaOne:
        popValue = 1
    case areaTwo:
        popValue = 2
    default: break
    }

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CityCell
   //resetting the color
    myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha:1.0)
    switch (segCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        myCell.myLabel.text = cityName[indexPath.row]

//I like to know how to add condition for button selected below
// so as to display popValue =1 when areaOne is tapped
//instead of me doing it manually like below

if citySelectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) && (popValue == 1) {
            myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha:0.5)
        }
        break
    case 1:
        myCell.myLabel.text  = townName[indexPath.row]
        if townSelectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
            myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha:0.5)
        }
        break
    default:break
    }
    return myCell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha:0.5)
    switch (segCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        if citySelectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
            let indexValue = citySelectedIndexPaths.indexOf(indexPath)
            citySelectedIndexPaths.removeAtIndex(indexValue)
        } else {
            citySelectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
        }
        break
    case 1:
        if townSelectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
            let indexValue = townSelectedIndexPaths.indexOf(indexPath)
            townSelectedIndexPaths.removeAtIndex(indexValue)
        } else {
            townSelectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
        }
        break
    default:break
    }
})
alertController.addAction(ok)
present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more context on what areaOne and areaTwo are. Maybe provide a screenshot?

Comment: In your logic now I see only  `cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha:0.5)`, do not see the snippet for reset `cell.backgroundColor` for the cell selected before.

Answer (score 0):

There is two delegate method which always fires after selection/ deselection of `UITableviewCell`. Please take a look on this following methods.

```
// Called after the user changes the selection.
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
optional public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) //Called after selection of cell

@available(iOS 3.0, *)
optional public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) //Called after deselection of cell.
```

Now your point is to change as per the button selection -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       let deSelectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? UITableviewCell
       deSelectedCell?.toggleCheckBox()        
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? UITableviewCell
        selectedCell?.toggleCheckBox()
}
```

Here in my case `toggleCheckBox()` is a function which determines a checkbox's selection/Deselection as per the cell selection/Deselection which is inside the cell itself.

Instead of updating cell selection inside `cellForRowAt indexPath` try updating inside these delegates. Though it is not properly clear that what situation you are trying to handle by seeing your question but you can update your main tableView data on this delegates as per the selection and deselection and update the entire table as per your need.

**EDIT**

Now as per your requirement you can make an array of objects for tableView data. Like as follows -

```
private var orderDetailsTableViewData: [[String: Any]] = [["cellSelectionColor": UIColor.blue], ["cellSelectionColor": UIColor.white]]
```

You just need to update the code as per the selection and update the tableView as per the requirements.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! UITableviewCell()
 if let cellColor = orderDetailsTableViewData[indexPath.row]["cellSelectionColor"] as? UIColor{
  cell.backgroundColor = cellColor
 }else{
  cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    orderDetailsTableViewData[indexPath.row].updateValue(UIColor.blue, forKey: "cellSelectionColor")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    orderDetailsTableViewData[indexPath.row].updateValue(UIColor.white, forKey: "cellSelectionColor")
}
```

Now after this you can update the table as per your requirements. BTW this is a rough idea about how you can keep selection of cell. For more critical things you can customise as per your need.

Hope this helped.:)

Comment: I updated my question, hope it is more clear, I have list of cities and town, I wanted the selected cities to remain highlighted depending on buttons pressed.